# What is the best way to re-create the primary key of a large table?

Tags: oracle, ddl

My case is that:

In Oracle DB, I have table (say table_a) with 2 columns only col_a and col_b
The number of columns is small, but with many rows

col_a is the primary key
Now, I need to add a new col (say col_c) to it and change the primary key from (col_a) to (col_a, col_c)

I do it in the following ways:

1. create col_c with a default value
2. drop the original primary key (col_a) including the index
3. re-create the primary key (col_a, col_c)

Steps 1 and 2 are fine and can be done in a fast time
but for Step 3, it fails after 1x mins with an error stating out of temp tablespace

Is there any way to do this better without increasing the limit of the tablespace?

Another way I can think of at the moment (also trying) is to create a new table (say table_a_temp) with the primary key (col_a, col_c). Then use "insert select" statement to copy data from table_a to table_a_temp. Finally, drop table_a and rename table_a_temp to table_a. But what I am afraid is that the archive redo log can exceed the limit.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: I would create a new table with NOLOGGING option, then insert with the APPEND hint, put it in LOGGING again and swap the tables with a rename. How would you populate the new `col_c` though?

Comment: @MarcoBaldelli Just want to make sure that I understand your idea. Make "NOLOGGING" disable the archive redo log, so that there is no archive log produced thus no need to worry about the limit of the log space. For the APPEND hint, it just make my insert faster but not affecting the tablespace limit too much because it just appends to the end instead of seeking free space table in-between. Also the subsequent insert without APPEND hint will still fill up the free space in-between. Finally, turn on the logging again after inserting all the records, make the archive redo log works again.

Comment: @MarcoBaldelli for populate the col_c, I just add the new column with default value, so that it is populate automatically. There should be some optimization in Oracle after certain ver, so that it is really fast in a few seconds.

Comment: this is known as "Direct-Path INSERT". If you choose to use NOLOGGING, you should take a db backup afterwards. You can find more information on the venerable [Ask Tom](https://asktom.oracle.com) website.

Comment: Just as a side observation, you would not be having this problem if you had followed sound design principles.  PK should be an arbitrary value (often using a sequence generator) that has no business meaning. Then If you have other columns that need to be "like" a PK, just put a unique index on them.

Comment: @kzfid I think you have a good handle on the problem, along with a good potential solution, but you may need to increase the temporary tablespace eventually anyway. Look at `DBA_SEGMENTS.BYTES` for the table - that's about the size of the temporary tablespace you'll need if the table is ever fully sorted or hashed or used as an intermediate data set. The chances are good that *eventually* someone will want to sort or hash the whole table, so you should have at least that much space available in `DBA_TEMP_FILES.MAXBYTES`.

Answer (score 1):

You could export the data, empty the table, create the index, sort the exported data and then import it back while taking advantage of the [SORTED INDEXES](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-571EC032-0C25-483A-BC0D-2C27A7B64D64.htm#SUTIL1316) clause in SQL*Loader.

You will be moving the task of sorting the data elsewhere, but you can't run away from sorting.